# Prove that $X \subset Y \implies f^{-1}(X) \subset f^{-1}(Y)$ .... Is invertibility assumed?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, inverse

Given a function f: A→B where X, Y $\subset$ B, prove that $X \subset Y \implies f^{-1}(X) \subset f^{-1}(Y)$

I was able to go ahead and prove this statement by applying the definition of the pre-image. My questions are:

1. Does this statement assume that function is invertible to begin with. Wouldn't a non-invertible function be a counterexample to this statement.
2. Will this statement hold if we replace $\subset$ with equality sign?

Comment: Have you used invertibility in proving this?

Comment: invertibility is not required. Notice that here $\subset $ means $\subseteq$. For $\subset $ being $\subsetneq$ it wouldn't work without further assumption (as injectivity if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @nejimban Yes. I started off with picking an arbitrary element in $f^{-1}(X)$ and then applying the definition of pre image and other stuff to prove that arbitrary x is also in $f^{-1}(Y)$. But if our function was not invertible i.e. $x^2$, then for the same element in codomain (Which would be subsets) the inverse wouldn't be subsets because they don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, it is not. This is  question about pre-images.
2. Yes; if $X=Y$, then $f^{-1}(X)=f^{-1}(Y)$.

Comment: If our function was not invertible then for the same element in codomain (Which would be subsets) the inverse wouldn't be subsets because they don't exist? So this statement would be false because we have a counterexample?

Comment: If $A\subset Y$ has no pre-image, then $f^{-1}(A)=\emptyset$. And $\emptyset$ is a subset of *every* set.

Comment: I see. Thank you!